# How to configure Eucalyptus for hybrid Cloud with Azure or AWS

Tags: azure, amazon-ec2, cloud, eucalyptus

I am trying to build a hybrid cloud that uses eucalyptus and maybe amazon or azure as the public part. I can create a private cloud in eucalyptus but how do i configure it to burst out to the public cloud when i the capacity for a certain instances in my private cloud is used up. I apologize i am new to this.

Answer (score 2):

Because Eucalyptus is AWS API compatible, you can build and deploy applications on AWS just as you would on your Eucalyptus clouds. For this reason AWS would be a better choice than Azure.

Answering the part about configuring Eucalyptus "burst out" is more complicated. There are at least two different definitions of "burst out". When your local cloud resources no longer meet requirements....

1) ...the application is brought up in the public cloud and served exclusively from there. For example, in a basic tier application you'd spin up presentation, business processing and data handling layers All user traffic is then directed to the application running in the public cloud.

....or...

2) only selected parts of the application are brought up in the public cloud. Perhaps just the presentation layer (end-user facing services). Or maybe your app was running out of storage, so you need to "burst" the data handling layer.

In both cases, you'll have needed to architected the application components to handle shifting between / among the clouds. You'll need a mechanism to know which part of the application is under resourced, then know how to respond appropriately. Your app may also need to deal with potential latency issues, cross-cloud security handling, load balancing configuration...and more.

Further, you may need to consider cost implications of using external resources. Which instance size(s) will you use? Which region(s) should you burst out to? How much block and / or object storage will you need? How will you keep private and public cloud resources in synch? How much data will transfers cost? If needed, how many elastic IPs will you provision? What's the mechanism you'll use to de-provision the public cloud resources when no longer needed so you don't continue running up a bill?

Neither scenario are automated by the underlying cloud infrastructure for reasons that may now be clear.

Answer (score 0):

I actually went with google cloud and azure in the end. I developed a c# app which had a round robin algorithm to either run a powershell script ot google shell python script.